# Check to see if a file can be opened error free with a program

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make a program that opens files in word after giving it file extension. But obviously not all files can be opened in word. So I was wondering if there's a way to get some kind of exception if word is unable to open the file. Any ideas would help. But I'm using VB.

```
try {
    $a = ./test.docx #pdf file changed to .docx
}
catch {
Write-Error "Error!" Exit
} Write-Host "No Error!"
```

Comment: Post the code you've already written, for starters.  If you know the path to Word's EXE you can cobble that up with the path to the file and pass it to SHELL; SHELL returns 0 on failure.

Comment: Well I'm in PS:
`try
{
$a = ./test.docx #pdf file changed to .docx
}
catch
{
Write-Error "Error!"
Exit
}
Write-Host "No Error!"`

It returns no error, I'm guessing because it doesn't catch a terminating error. So I'm just trying to figure a way to catch an error within word.

Comment: I'm puzzled.  You mention that you're using VB and have tagged the question with VBA, but your code isn't either.

Comment: yeah sorry, It's because I don't have any code on this. That's the issue. Besides doing a try catch, which doesn't work, I have no idea what to do. So I'm willing to get advice within any language.

Comment: Do youu know the actual content of the files (ie, that they really ARE Word, RTF, TXT, whatever files)?  If so, it'd be fairly simple to get a list of the file types that Word can open and either launch Word with the filename on the command line, shellexecute the file or whatever.  If you don't know the content of the files, then appending extensions willy-nilly is sort of odd, unless you're stuck trying every extension Word understands in the hopes of finding one that actually works.  In that case you'll need to automate Word, call its file open method and trap any errors that occur.

Comment: I do know that it will always either be a docx or xlsx. So it will either open or word or excel. I guess calling the file open method would be the only way. How would that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments above, I'd suggest that you look up the ShellExecute WinAPI call.

If you pass the file (full path, name, extension) to ShellExecute, Windows figures out what app is registered to open the file and calls it for you.  In other words, if you call ShellExecute on c:\some_dir\myfile.docx it'll open the file in Word or return a value indicating that there was an error.

There's an example here on my PPT FAQ site, along with a link to much more info on Randy Birch's *superb* site:

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00479_ShellExecute_Example.htm

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for, I just need to get the return values and I'll be set. Thanks a lot for your help!